# ngGrid cellFilter and cellTemplate do not work together

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid, celltemplate, cell-formatting

I use **ngGrid** to display my data. I would like to use cellFilter and cellTemplate together for the specific column, but seems they do not work together. 
when I use cellFilter or cellTemplate seperately they work perfect. Basically, I would like to format the value of the cells in this way (e.g 500000 --> 500,000; 1000000 --> 1,000,000) and also I would like to make negative values in a red colour. How can I solve this? Thanks!

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'data',
        columnDefs: [
            {
                field: 'Settled',
                cellFilter: 'number',
                cellTemplate: '<div ng-class="{red: row.getProperty(col.field) < 0}"><div class="ngCellText">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div></div>'
            }]
        }
```

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer myself :p

It is so simple.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'data',
        columnDefs: [
            {
                field: 'Settled',
                cellTemplate: '<div ng-class="{red: row.getProperty(col.field) < 0}"><div class="ngCellText">{{row.getProperty(col.field) | number }}</div></div>'
            }]
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

As ng-grid is now UI-Grid v3.x, referencing the default template for ui-grid/uiGridCell

```
$templateCache.put('ui-grid/uiGridCell',
  "<div class=\"ui-grid-cell-contents\" title=\"TOOLTIP\">{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</div>"
);
```

I would say the cellTemplate in the updated UI-Grid should be the following:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'data',
        columnDefs: [
            {
                field: 'Settled',
                cellFilter: 'number',
                cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" ng-class="{red: COL_FIELD < 0}">{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</div>'
            }]
        }
```

You can also use the `cellClass` property instead, and leave the cell template default. However, this applies the class to the `.ui-grid-cell`. The cell template would apply the class to the child of `.ui-grid-cell`, which in my example above is `.ui-grid-cell-contents`. Whichever works for your situation, I suppose.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'data',
    columnDefs: [
        {
            field: 'Settled',
            cellFilter: 'number',
            cellClass: function (grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex) {
                var cellVal = grid.getCellValue(row, col);
                return (cellVal < 0) ? 'red' : '';
            }
        }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Mammadj's answer I could work out my own *cellTemplate* combined with *cellFilter*. Here is my solution for reference, where executionStatus is the value of the cell which was previously used as `cellFilter: 'emJobStateLabel'`. Here the executionStatus is piped to emJobStateLabel in a cell template:

```
cellTemplate: '<div class="em-row">{{row.entity.executionStatus | emJobStateLabel}} {{row.entity["previewStatus"]==\'New\'?\'\':\'(\'+row.entity.previewStatus+\')\'}}</div>'
```

Don't forget to remove the property cellFilter.